# How to disable a Visual Studio extension for a specific solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I work on a bunch of different solutions. One solution in particular is massive, and ReSharper causes Visual Studio to hang. So I am hoping to disable ReSharper for that one solution, and leave ReSharper enabled for all other solutions. Is this possible?

Today, I am enabling/disabling ReSharper as needed, but that is not ideal.

Comment: If ReSharper doesn’t have a setting for it, to my knowledge VS doesn’t have any. R# is known to have performance issues and VS+Roslyn provide pretty much everything out of the box so most devs I know stopped using it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I've heard. I have tried going without R#, but I found myself missing some features. To be fair, I'm on old versions of VS and .NET Framework. I expect it's probably different on the latest VS and .NET.

Comment: It might be possible to do this with different version of VS. Install ReSharper in VS2022, but not install in VS2019.

Comment: That works. I disabled R# in VS2017 and enabled R# in VS2019.